# Putting a hyperlink in a MessageBox

Tags: vba, ms-access, hyperlink, ms-access-2010, messagebox

Is it possible to add a hyperlink to a messagebox?  I'm trying to do something like this:

```
   MsgBox "Sorry, but you have an out-of-date database version.  Please redownload via the batch file to ensure that you have the latest version. Contact the administrator of this database or your manager if you need help." & vbCr _
        & vbCr _
        & "Your current database version is " & CurrentVer & " which may be out of date. The current database version prescribed on the network share is " & FileVer & ". They must match in order for you to proceed." & vbCr _
        & vbCr _
        & "For CSC self-help instructions on how to reload the most current version of the PRF Intake Tool to your computer, please click the link below to be directed to CSC Online instructions." & vbCr _
        & vbCr _
        & "http://www.OurSite.com/online/Solutions/Search_Results.asp?opsystem=7&keywords=PRF+Intake+Tool&Category=", , "There is a problem..."
```

The problem is, the hyperlink isn't clickable.  I'd like to do this so that the users can just click the link and have the download begin automatically.

I'm using Access 2010 in a Win7 environment.

Comment: No but you could ask the user if they wanted to open the link and then navigate IE to the location for example.

Comment: or build a custom form for the messagebox and then you could add in the hyperlink

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A straight-forward answer is **NO**. MsgBox does not allow hyperlinks, just plain text.

Thus, here is a workaround that should work alright.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

intMessage = MsgBox("Sorry, but you have an out-of-date database version.  Please redownload via the batch file to ensure that you have the latest version. Contact the administrator of this database or your manager if you need help." & vbCr _
        & vbCr _
        & "Your current database version is " & CurrentVer & " which may be out of date. The current database version prescribed on the network share is " & FileVer & ". They must match in order for you to proceed." & vbCr _
        & vbCr _
        & "Would you like to learn more about CSC self-help instructions on how to reload the most current version of the PRF Intake Tool to your computer?", _
        vbYesNo, "There is a problem...")

If intMessage = vbYes Then
    objShell.Run ("http://www.OurSite.com/online/Solutions/Search_Results.asp?opsystem=7&keywords=PRF+Intake+Tool&Category=")
Else
    Wscript.Quit
End If
```

If underline style is a requirement, then you should just create your own User Form as described at http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip71.htm. Here are the steps:

1. Add a `Label` object and type your message
2. Make the Label blue (`ForeColor`) and underlined (`Font`) so it looks like a typical hyperlink.
3. Set the Label's `MousePointer` property to *99 - fmMousePointerCustom*
4. Specify the cursor file for the Label's `MouseIcon` image (if you have one).
5. Double-click the Label and create a subroutine the *Click* event. Here's a sample code:

   ```
   Private Sub Label1_Click()
     Link = "http://www.YOUR_SITE.com"
     On Error GoTo NoCanDo
     ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Link, NewWindow:=True
     Unload Me
     Exit Sub
    NoCanDo:
     MsgBox "Cannot open " & Link End Sub
   ```

To create a "mail to" hyperlink, use a statement like this:

```
Link = "mailto:someone@somewhere.com"
```