# VBA to return hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, vlookup

I have written a macro that performs a `VLookup` but I need it to return a hyperlink and not just a text string. There is a hyperlink in the range so all I need it to do is copy it into my result.

How can I change this VBA?

```
Sub check()
    On Error GoTo MyerrorHandler:
    Dim claim_number As String
    Dim here As String
    claim_number = InputBox("please enter claim number")
    If Len(claim_number) > 0 Then
    Set myrange = Range("claims")
    here = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(claim_number, myrange, 3, False)
    MsgBox "Claim has been investigted, info is here " & here

    Else
    MsgBox "You didn't enter a claim number"
    End If
    Exit Sub

    MyerrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Claim has not been invsetigated"
    End If

End Sub
```

The `VLookup` works fine but instead of copying the hyperlink from my range it just returns the text. I have tried everything but cannot get it to work.

Comment: You cannot have hyperlink on msgbox - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705916/putting-a-hyperlink-in-a-messagebox

Comment: Hyperlink to where? why do you need a hyperlink?

Comment: You can't have a hyperlink on a `MsgBox`, but you could put up a `vbYesNo` box and ask the user if they want to follow the hyperlink, then programatically send them to it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. How do i put a vbYesNo box on to the end of my macro with the option to programatically send them the relevant hyperlink?

Comment: I wanted some way of giving the option to view or be redirected the relevent file that was returned by the vlookup. Is that possible?